# Preloading UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm having an problem preloading a UIWebView into a second view controller.

I receive no errors, just nothing loads in the second view.

My preload function in the first view is as follows..

```
func preloadShop(){
        let preload = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Shop") as! ViewController


        preload.loadWebView()
        print("preloading shop")
    }
```

and my second view function is..

```
func loadWebView(){


        let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height))
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.co.uk")!))

        self.view.addSubview(webView)    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you show your ViewControllers via segue,

```
let preload = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Shop") as! ViewController
```

will create a new instance of your ViewController and not the current.

If you'd like to preload the content of webview, you need to create a property in your shooting ViewController and present if manually from there, without a segue.

You should also put your loading-method inside *viewDidLoad* and call

```
preload.view.layoutSubviews()
```

instead of

```
preload.loadWebView()
```

That makes sure, the view is loaded.